# Fermat numbers are congruent to $17$ or $47$ modulo $210$. Can we generalize this result?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, primorial

Let $n>1$ be an integer and $F_n:=2^{2^n}+1$.

**Result:** $n$ even: $F_n\equiv17\pmod{210}$

**Result:** $n$ odd: $F_n\equiv47\pmod{210}$

**Proof:** Suppose $n$ even, $F_n - 1\equiv16\pmod{210}$. Then $2^{2^{n+2}}=({2^{2^n}})^4\equiv16^4\pmod{210}\equiv16\pmod{210}$ and $F_{n+2}\equiv17\pmod{210}$. The proof is the same if $n$ is odd.

I found that result using primoradic (see stub OEIS: https://oeis.org/wiki/Primorial_numeral_system).

That's the way I found that result [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132592/a-result-about-fermats-numbers-is-my-proof-correct-is-that-result-useful-can?rq=1), which I did't know before and I wonder if there are other results with $2310$, $30030,\ldots$ (primorials)

Comment: For $2310$, the sequence is eventually periodic of order $4$.  Specifically, it goes $\{5, \overline {17,257,857,457}\}$. This is just a simnple matter of modular arithmetic.  I assume the other moduli work similarly.

Comment: Update, $30030$ also yields something periodic of order $4$.  Specifically $\{5,\overline {17,257,5477,16637}\}$.  Again, just a routine modular computation.  The period is $5$ for $510510$ and it is $12$ for $9699690$.   I don't really see any pattern here, but it's just a few examples.

Comment: What interests me is not so much this result as the fact that the use of primoradic led me to it

Comment: I don't see any connection at all.  Obviously the sequence is periodic.  We can write $F_n=(F_{n-1}-1)^2+1$, so if you ever repeat a value (which, obviously, you must if you are working $\pmod m$) then the sequence is periodic after that.

Comment: As lulu mentions, the sequence is obviously periodic. Let me merely add that the periods being small should not be surprising - if $n$ is a product of primes, then the period mod $n$ is the lcm of periods mod primes dividing $n$. Primorials are products of few small primes, so the periods couldn't be large either.

Comment: Via the method in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4132633/242) to your prior question: $\,F_{n+2} = (F_n-1)^4+1\,$ and $\color{#0a0}{17}$ and $\color{#c00}{47}$ are fixed points of $\,f(x) = (x-1)^4+1\bmod {210},$ the complete list being $1,2,16,\color{#0a0}{17},22,26,31,37,\color{#c00}{47},52,61,71,82,86,92,101,106,107,121,122,127,131,136,142,152,157,166,176,187,191,197,206,\,$ which are the solutions of $\,x\equiv 1,2\pmod{\!2,3,5,7}$ along with $\,x\equiv 3,5\pmod{\!7}.\ $ With $\,z=x-1\,$ the fixed points are roots of $\,z^4-z\,$ so $0$ and cube roots of $\,1\pmod{p}\ \ $

Comment: @lulu : for 2310, ok. 17=0x210+17; 257=1x210+47; 857 = 4x210+17 ; 467 = 2x210+47. Thanks